# There is null in @Autowired field when try to inject in spring-quartz job?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, quartz

There is spring-application used with spring-batch and spring-quartz

There is @Service class that launch spring-batch and named MyService.

```
@Service
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    Job processExportJob;

    public void helloMethod() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(processExportJob, jobParameters);
    }
}
```

There is spring-quarts job and config that try to inject this serrvice and launch method helloMethod()
If job contains only logger, there is no problem and works okey.

Then, I try to inject my service in one of field. After every application launch, first time, job contains this field, but in next time there is null in this field.

I tried to just create my service by new:
MyService service = new MyService();

But in service all autowired fields are null after first successful launch

Application is deployed on webshere 8.5.5.13(cluster with 2 nodes), oracle11g and spring4. Java8.

Then, using the `@Autowired` annotation I inject the service into the job it this job works exactly once. The injected field is null during all the subsequent job executions. 
Moreover, if I create the service outside spring:

```
MyService service  = new MyService();


@DisallowConcurrentExecution
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class MyJob implements Job {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    private static final String MESSAGE = "===================================QUARTZ TACT===================================";
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, MESSAGE);
        try {
            service.helloMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, " Failed..");
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wher created sheduler with job and trigger, scheduler willserialized in database. Job-field is marked such as transient, so it doen't save in database. Then it created by new when need to use, but new create object not in applicationContext..

Answer (score 0):

From different place is heplful to use this:

```
ApplicationContext springContext =
                    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getServletContext());

Object bean = springContext.getBean("myService");
```

It solved my issue